# NZEC in spoj FACKT

Tags: python

I was trying to solve this problem http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FACKT/, and I keep getting a Non-Zero Exit Code (NZEC). How exactly do I figure out what to change in the code to overcome this?

Here is the code

```
import math
import sys
def cal_num(n):

    i = 1
    f = 1
    while f<n:
        f *= i
        i = i + 1
    return i-1


while 1:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    n = int(line)
    x = cal_num(n)
    y = math.factorial(2*x)
    l = int(math.ceil(math.log(y,10)))
    print (x,l)
```

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Try `print x, l`. The brackets make it a tuple, which does not get printed in the right format. I don't see how that would give you Non-Zero Exit Code though.

Answer (score 0):

The line returned will have the newline, won't be empty or None.
Try this:

```
if line == "\n":
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

In this question, you have to read a single number as input. I don't see any reason for having the while loop.

```
import math
import sys
def cal_num(n):

    i = 1
    f = 1
    while f<n:
        f *= i
        i = i + 1
    return i-1

def main():    # Replace while with a function.
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line == "":
        return    # Replace break with return
    n = int(line)
    x = cal_num(n)
    y = math.factorial(2*x)
    l = int(math.ceil(math.log(y,10)))
    print x,l

main()
```